# tw-elements with angular Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')

Tags: angular, tailwind-css, tailwind-elements

Hello evry one i am learning Angular using tailwind and tailwind-element
The css is working well
but i got the following error when i select input in my form

```
> zone.js:1714 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
> at d._applyNotch (node_modules\tw-elements\dist\js\index.min.js:11:168833)
> at d._getElements (node_modules\tw-elements\dist\js\index.min.js:11:169384)
> at node_modules\tw-elements\dist\js\index.min.js:11:169140
> at J (node_modules\tw-elements\dist\js\index.min.js:11:72325)
> at d._activate (node_modules\tw-elements\dist\js\index.min.js:11:169133)
> at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (node_modules\tw-elements\dist\js\index.min.js:11:169904)
> at HTMLDocument.i (node_modules\tw-elements\dist\js\index.min.js:11:74898)
> at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:409:31)
> at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:47)
> at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:490:34)
```

i have the following version

```
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1502.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.2.4
@angular-devkit/core            15.2.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.2.4
@angular/cli                    15.2.4
@schematics/angular             15.2.4
rxjs                            7.8.0
typescript                      4.9.5
```

my tailwind conf

```
> /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./node_modules/tw-elements/dist/js/**/*.js"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require("tw-elements/dist/plugin")]
  `your text`
}
```

in my angular.json i add

```
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/tw-elements/dist/js/index.min.js"
            ]
```

Comment: are you importing the tw-elements in the app-component.ts? or initializing it in the components you are using?

Comment: am using  import  "tw-elements";
in my app.component.ts